# Who to verify date on sql request

Tags: php, mysql, sql, date

I have a problem with my script, when I try :

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM logs WHERE time_activation!= '2022-03-20'";
```

It's works !But if I use a variable, it doesn't work :

```
$today = date("Y-m-d");
$sql = "SELECT * FROM logs WHERE time_activation!= $today";
```

I have try this :

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM logs WHERE time_activation!= `$today`";
```

and this :

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM logs WHERE time_activation!= #$today#";
```

Nothing works :( could you help me please

Comment: BUT Your script will be open to [SQL Injection Attack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174). 
Even [if you are escaping inputs, its not safe!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187)
You should always use [prepared parameterized statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) 
in either the `MYSQLI_` or `PDO` API's instead of concatenating user provided values into the query. Never trust ANY user input!

Comment: I use prepare request and pdo....  I simplified for the example...

Comment: Then `WHERE time_activation!= :today"` then `prepare()` and then `bindParam()` then `execute()`